# Customize Colors for Bash Terminal

Tags: bash, bashrc, colors

I found this nice color library called [Solarize](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) which promises to liven up my hacking experience with a color terminal.

[image]

I am not where to add the Solarize files to change.  I found some instructions if you want to use [`tmux`](https://github.com/seebi/tmux-colors-solarized) and indeed I installed tmux and the script but my colors don't really change.

Comment: I also found this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

Comment: Solorize is a theme for vim/emacs/IDEA/NetBeans etc. [Here on site](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized#editors-ides) are links to separate themes to all editors/IDEs.

Comment: Nice, but WHERE do I find what the color scheme indicates? In my current scheme white seems to be "file" , blue "directory" , the rest I am left to guessing.

Answer (score 5):

### Personal background

I spend a lot of time in GVim which I’ve configured to use the Solarized colour and I love it; I really like being able to switch back and forth between the light and dark versions (depending on the ambient light conditions).

Once I tried it configuring my terminal emulator and it worked fine on my local computer because I had other software set up to make use of the solarized colour scheme, e.g., the `LS_COLORS` environment variable.

However, I log on to a few other servers using SSH and I never got around to configuring all the different remote environments so I reverted to a plain old black background for my terminal emulator.

### Configuring Gnome Terminal

You don’t say which terminal emulator you’re using but since you’re running Ubuntu, Gnome Terminal is available to you and you can get the Solarized colour scheme by following the instructions from [Solarized Colorscheme for Gnome Terminal](https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized).

If you’re not familiar with using Git, you can download the files from the [zip file](https://github.com/Anthony25/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized/archive/master.zip).

When you have that working, be sure to install and configure [Solarized Color Theme for GNU ls (as setup by GNU dircolors)](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized).  This sets the `LS_COLORS` environment variable so that `ls --color` displays colours that work with a terminal which has a light or dark Solarized background instead of a black or white background. Note: the documentation can be daunting as it goes into a lot of detail about terminals.

The following links should also be useful:

- [Color schemes, Gnome Terminal documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/app-colors.html.en)
- [Solarized colors on Gnome Terminal](http://misctechmusings.com/solarized-colors-on-gnome-terminal/)
- [Solarized: A Must Have Color Scheme For Gnome Terminal, Vim, Gedit And Lots More](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/solarized-must-have-color-paletter-for.html)

*Edit:* Beginning with Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet), gnome-terminal includes Solarized as one of its preset colour schemes.

Comment: Note: Beginning with Ubuntu Vivid, gnome-terminal ships the Solarized color theme by default. No need to install anything, just open its preferences and select it.

Comment: Thanks @egmont - I've updated my answer to include that important update.